# Getting class elements length in spec.ts Angular4

Tags: angular

I have a simple spec.ts, where i am getting an array from service. Same service render a table in *ngFor inside the component. Table- tr has a class  `.dataTr`. How can i know how much tr are in the table.

I tried this.

```
it('Should increase page number on paginator next Click', async(() => {   

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => { 
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(component.dataSource.length);
        let tr = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dataTr'))[1];
        console.log(tr);
        expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
    });


}));
```

Comment: Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
let numTrs = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('tr')).length;
expect(numTrs).toBe(/* Expected Number */);
```

or if you want to search only within the table:

```
let tableDe = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dataTr'));
expect(tableDe.queryAll(By.css('tr')).length).toBe(/* Expected Number */);
```